# AWK SED Manipulate text to sort it as CSV

Tags: csv, text, awk, sed

I have this input file

```
SHARED FOLDER: \\SERVERC1\"uh4" 

Share name        \\SERVERC1\uh4
Path              C:\vol\CN_FS4\CN_QT01\FILESERVER43\userhome
Remark            
Maximum users     No limit
Users             0
Permissions:
WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL
WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL
WINDOM\ADMINDA16   :  FULL CONTROL
The command completed successfully.
============================================================================================================  
SHARED FOLDER: \\SERVERC1\"uh5" 

Share name        \\SERVERC1\uh5
Path              C:\vol\CN_FS2\CN_QT01\FILESERVER01\userhome
Remark            
Maximum users     No limit
Users             0
Permissions:
WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL
WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL
WINDOM\ADMINDA20   :  FULL CONTROL
The command completed successfully.
============================================================================================================
```

I need this output :

```
\\SERVERC1\uh4;C:\vol\CN_FS4\CN_QT01\FILESERVER43\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA16   :  FULL CONTROL
\\SERVERC1\uh5;C:\vol\CN_FS2\CN_QT01\FILESERVER01\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA20   :  FULL CONTROL
```

Do you have any suggestion?
I have no idea how to do it. I tried to do: 
sed -n "/Permissions:/,/The command completed succesfully/p"  to get the permissions only but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -nE 's/^Share name *(\\\\.*)/\1;/p;s/^Path *(.*)$/\1;/p;s/^WINDOM.*/&;/p' input.txt | tr -d "\n" | sed 's/;\\\\/;\n\\\\/g' | sed 's/;$//'
```

Output:

```
\\SERVERC1\uh4;C:\vol\CN_FS4\CN_QT01\FILESERVER43\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA16   :  FULL CONTROL
\\SERVERC1\uh5;C:\vol\CN_FS2\CN_QT01\FILESERVER01\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA20   :  FULL CONTROL
```

Answer (score 2):

Through grep and paste,

```
$ grep -oP '^(Share name|Path)\s+\K.*|^WINDOM\\.*' file | paste -d';' - - - - -
\\SERVERC1\uh4;C:\vol\CN_FS4\CN_QT01\FILESERVER43\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA16   :  FULL CONTROL
\\SERVERC1\uh5;C:\vol\CN_FS2\CN_QT01\FILESERVER01\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA20   :  FULL CONTROL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version, all done in one command.

```
awk '{i++} i==3 {d=$3} i==4 {d=d";"$2} i>8 && i<12 {d=d";"$0} /===/{print d;i=d=""}' file
```

```
\\SERVERC1\uh4;C:\vol\CN_FS4\CN_QT01\FILESERVER43\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA16   :  FULL CONTROL
\\SERVERC1\uh5;C:\vol\CN_FS2\CN_QT01\FILESERVER01\userhome;WINDOM\NASCIFSMIG01:  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA14b  :  FULL CONTROL;WINDOM\ADMINDA20   :  FULL CONTROL
```

---

Shorten some:

```
awk '++i==3{d=$3} i==4{d=d";"$2} i>8&&i<12{d=d";"$0} /===/{print d;i=d=""}' file
```